# How to override or redefine vue router?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-router

### My problems

Hi guys, 

I am building a website that uses vuejs (vue, vuex, vue-router). Besides, I have used another template which is material dashboard (this template uses bootrsap4 and a custom js file).

At first, everything was very convenient, my vue-router worked perfectly. But when I checked the interface on my phone, there was a problem:

[image]

In this interface, the user menu in the upper right corner works with the vue-router normally, my page does not reload every time the url changes.

[image]

But when I changed the browser size, made it smaller and the user menu bar will now show as above. The problem now is that the links act like a normal anchor tag, and my page re-loads every time the URL changes.

### Found the cause

This is the code of the user menu bar.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
                <div class="navbar-form"></div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:;" id="navbarDropdownProfile" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                            <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                                Account
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownProfile">
                            <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/test">Profile</router-link>
                            <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/another_one">Settings</router-link>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log out</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

#### The problem is in the template's javascript custom file

They use a function that rewrites the menu bar whenever the window size gets smaller and
this may accidentally overwrite or disrupt the vue-router. The code is as follows:

```js
initRightMenu: debounce(function() {
    $sidebar_wrapper = $('.sidebar-wrapper');

    if (!mobile_menu_initialized) {
      $navbar = $('nav').find('.navbar-collapse').children('.navbar-nav');

      mobile_menu_content = '';

      nav_content = $navbar.html();

      nav_content = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-mobile-menu">' + nav_content + '</ul>';

      navbar_form = $('nav').find('.navbar-form').get(0).outerHTML;

      $sidebar_nav = $sidebar_wrapper.find(' > .nav');

      // insert the navbar form before the sidebar list
      $nav_content = $(nav_content);
      $navbar_form = $(navbar_form);
      $nav_content.insertBefore($sidebar_nav);
      $navbar_form.insertBefore($nav_content);

      $(".sidebar-wrapper .dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

      });

      // simulate resize so all the charts/maps will be redrawn
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

      mobile_menu_initialized = true;
    } else {
      if ($(window).width() > 991) {
        // reset all the additions that we made for the sidebar wrapper only if the screen is bigger than 991px
        $sidebar_wrapper.find('.navbar-form').remove();
        $sidebar_wrapper.find('.nav-mobile-menu').remove();

        mobile_menu_initialized = false;
      }
    }
  }, 200),
```

### What have I tried

I tried rewriting javascript in their js file as follows:

```
nav_content = $navbar.html(); // I turned this


// into this
nav_content = `<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:;" id="navbarDropdownProfile" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                            <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                                Account
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownProfile">
                            <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/test">Profile</router-link>
                            <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="another_one">Settings</router-link>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log out</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>`
```

But it still does not work

#### To be more clear

I tried printing out nav_content, everything seems right. I think the problem is `$nav_content = $(nav_content);`

***Is the problem I pointed out correct? If yes, I'd appreciate it if I got your advice, thank you.***